# редирект сайта, сломался сайт

Tags: html

проблема: сайт сначала был такой, [www.gls-trade.ru](http://www.gls-trade.ru)
через плагин rederection я поменяла на gls-trade.ru
В админку зайти не могу, как исправить? могу попасть через ftp к данным

Comment: Может в базе его можно деактивировать?

Comment: а как это можно сделать?

Comment: Ну через phpmyadmin войти например или другое приложение, там посмотреть. Я в вордпресс не разбираюсь, но думаю там все просто

Comment: в админку вордпрес я не могу зайти, только через ftp попасть могу

Comment: Вам не нужна админка в вордпрес, а визуальный доступ к базе, посмотрите в панели хостинга

Comment: @Vadim если человек не совсем понимает каким образом можно получить доступ к БД, боюсь что получив к ней доступ, ничего хорошего из этого не выйдет.

Comment: Ну, пока разберется, там кто-нибудь конкретно подскажет что надо изменить

Comment: @Simon
вы можете подсказать, куда там дальше заходить?

Comment: @MAB переходите в phpMyAdmin, там ищете базу данных которая используется Вашим сайтом, ее название можете посмотреть в файле wp-config.php который в корне сайта. Ищете, если я не ошибаюсь, таблицу `wp_redirection_items` (имейте ввиду что префикс может быть не обязательно wp, зависит от Вашего конфига), затем ищете нужный Вам редирект.

Comment: @MAB но возможно лучшим вариантом будет восстановить базу из бекапа сделанного до того как Вы добавили редирект. Попросить об этом можете Вашего хостера в технической поддержке, обычно раз в день бекапы делаются.

Comment: @MAB ну и как,починили сайт?

Comment: @ПростаMiha на хостинге попросили бекап, откатили.
Но почему-то не могу зайти в админку.. просто грузит и все сайт
Может что-то подскажите?

Comment: @MAB возможно редирект в кэше браузера засел, попробуйте из инкогнито.